# How to prove the following statement in Boyd & Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization with the help of composition rules

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

It is written in the book that if $h(x)$ is convex then $f(x)=h(Ax+b)$ is also convex. Now according to the composition rules if we write $f(x)=h(g(x))$ where $g(x)=Ax+b$ then if

1. $h(x)$ is convex and nondecreasing and $g(x)$ is also convex then $f(x)$ will be convex. Although $g(x)$ is convex here, due to being affine, and $h(x)$ is convex by assumption but how can we be sure that $h(x)$ is nondecreasing?
2. $h(x)$ is convex and non-increasing and $g(x)$ is concave then $f(x)$ will be convex. Although $g(x)$ is concave here, due to being affine, and $h(x)$ is convex by assumption but how can we be sure that $h(x)$ is nonincreasing?

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither of those composition rules apply. Affine composition is a different rule. This is quite important, because affine composition is true even if the outer function is non-monotonic.

Comment: @MichaelGrant thank you for your comment. I think the book does not provide any proof of the statement. However, it is used in several exercises. So what could be the easiest way to proof this statement?

Comment: Try applying the definition of a convex function.

Comment: @Rahul thank you. I got the desired result.

Comment: From which chapter?